# jQuery Delegating to Close Boxy Dialogs

Tags: jquery, delegates, boxy

currently, i am using the following to close a dialog

```
<button onClick="Boxy.get(this).hideAndUnload(); return false;">Cancel</button>
```

but i want to do something like

```
<button class="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
```

to close the dialog

i tried to use jquery `delegate()` to close the dialog but it does not work. fyi, i am loading the whole form dynamically using ajax. eg.

```
$.get("add/text.html", function(data) {
  var b = new Boxy(data, {
    title: "Add Text Post",
    modal: true,
  });
  $.getScript("js/tinymce.config.js");
  b.show();
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Boxy website](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/) you could use **.close** css class:

> .close
>
> ```
> Any elements with this class will be hooked up to close the dialog on
> ```
>
> click.

As for a second thought: Have you tried using this kind of logic?

```
    $('.btnCancel').click(function(){
     Boxy.get(this).hideAndUnload(); return false;
});
```

Comment: I hadn't looked at the Boxy website (you answered before I found it), but your second suggestion looks like my first-thought on how to effect the OP's intent. Though I'm up-voting for having the sense to recommend using the in-built feature of Boxy itself, rather than complicating things via additional jQuery. Good call =)